# How to create VBA code & Excel code to Calculate column BX to zero in excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image: File screenshot]

I have a Value in columns AJ9, AL9, AN9, AP9, AT9, AV9, AX9, AZ9, BB9, BD9, & BF9. Total in Cell BQ9 and latest total as of today in BT9.  Cell BX having the difference between BT9 minus BQ9. If there is difference in BX9, I need to minus from reduce the value in BF9, if not covered need to minus from BD9 and follows until my BX9 become 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This isn't a code-writing service; please see [ask]. Post your data as a [markdown table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) along with what code you have tried, and we can help you identify what's wrong with the code and fix it.